# World company database?

Tags: stock-market, markets, financial-markets

I need to find the list of companies with their respective market caps and their sectors of activities.

For now I have found these two links:
• https://goo.gl/E8WJzu
• http://goo.gl/vuHDuF

But I need to find more.

Comment: Reuters DataStream?

Comment: Datastream is amazing but it is a bit expensive. I'd suggest you to go for Yahoo Finance, pick up their API and make your own Python script (to export it csv, json or whatever). The same goes for Google Finance, but I believe it is not easy to access nowadays.